# Code changes not being included when compiling in Visual C# Express 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

At seemingly random times, whenever I load up VC# Express for the day and start working, any changes I make to my code don't get reflected in my debug runs. It's as if VC just refuses to compile the code and just runs the old already-compiled version. Deleting the "bin" folder in the project directory doesn't help, as then VC just complains that it can't find the *.exe instead of recompiling. Doing a rebuild helps, but only for that one rebuild, so I'm continuously having to rebuild the solution to see any changes, which is really slow.

The only way I've found to get rid of this problem (for maybe a week or two) is to create a new project and manually copy over my code. Needless to say, this is really frustrating and tedious. Is this a documented issue? What can be done to fix it? Searching online doesn't really turn up any answers, as the search terms most applicable to the problem bring up a lot of noise results.

Comment: What kind of project? Web site?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might see if the project you are working on is set to Build when the solution builds.  To check this, right-click your Solution and go to Properties.  Click the Configuration Properties node on the left and make sure all of the projects you want to build are checked on the ride side for your given build type.

**UPDATE:** Also, what is the timestamp on your build files?  Is the timestamp getting updated on your build?

Comment: I would say that too, but the OP said he is able to "workaround" the issue if he creates a new project/solution the issue disappears for a while.

Comment: I tried the Configuration Properties; lo and behold, my main project was not checked under the "Build" field! Thank you SO much! This problem had been plaguing me for months!

Comment: However, being the coder that I am, I'm now curious as to why it sometimes worked and sometimes didn't, and what triggered it to not work.

Comment: @Mark - Good question.  I haven't used the Express version much.  I've always manually adjusted the builds.  Typically, when you add a new project, it will automatically be checked.  Sounds like something is triggering it to turn off - you'll have to experiment and see.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when working on a network drive, and the time on the server was out of sync.  Linux+Samba accessed by Win7 Pro and VB 2010 Express.

Correcting the time-difference solved the issue.

Answer (score -1):

click on BUILD-->REBUILD SOLUTION  and you are now good to go

Comment: He already said helps doing this in his question, and it only helps for one build.

Comment: I experience the same thing the Op does every so often and this solution works. Would love to understand why all of a sudden VS refuses to compile the current files. Even when deleting the entire Debug directory, a build is produced reflecting old source files that no longer exist! What is the VS black magic...?